# How do I retrieve resource name from imagespan drawable?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, emoji, imagespan

I have an array of ImageSpan type which contains icons that were added to a TextEdit. It is called: ImageSpan[] itemSpans;

When I want to know which icon was typed in the EditText field - I loop through the array

```
for (int x = 0; x < itemSpans.length; x++) {
String Icon="";
if (itemSpans[x].getDrawable().equals(MyWinkIconImageView.getDrawable())) {

                Icon = ":-)";
            }
}
```

MyWinkIconImageView is a variable linked to ImageView control that points to a resource, Eg: R.Drawable.MyIcon

This is how how do it. Even if it is a bit wrong.

**The thing is:** I want to get the drawable's resource name from itemSpans[x].getDrawable() instead of pointing to the ImageView control, meaning that I want to know which itemSpans[x] is currently drawn in the EditText rather than to check its ImageView.

I wish to do something like that:

```
if (itemSpans[x].getDrawable().equals(R.Drawable.Smiley)
{
Icon=":-)";
}
if (itemSpans[x].getDrawable().equals(R.Drawable.Sad)
{
Icon=":-(";
}
```

and so on...

Again, the `itemSpans[x].getDrawable()` array contain the image resources (icons from `R.Drawable.xxxx`) that currently exist in the EditText after the user typed them. I just don't know how to get the `R.drawable.xxxx` resource name from `itemSpans[x]` in order to compare them like I mentioned above.